# Accessing a method of a class object stored in a vector using an Iterator. How?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, vector, iterator

Hey first question I'm asking here many thanks in advance. 
I'm using a vector to store a series of pointers to objects of a class CSquare, I want to have an iterator that I can pass around so that I can access the functions of a certain object. This is my current code to attempt this with no luck. IntteliSense telling me that there are 'No members Available'.

```
    vector <CSquare*> pSquares;
    //filled in vector
    vector<CSquare*>::iterator tempIt = pSquares.begin();
    tempIt->getName();
```

Not sure what else to add, but if you need anything else to help me out please say.

Again thanks a lot.

Edit: Problem solved, I had to dereference twice. The following code works, thought I'd just leave this up incase anyone else need the same help, thanks for looking anyway.

```
    vector <CSquare*> pSquares;
    //filled in vector
    vector<CSquare*>::iterator tempIt = pSquares.begin();
    (**tempIt).getName();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that you need to dereference the iterator to get the pointed-to thing. Because this is a `vector<CSquare*>`, your iterator is effectively a pointer-to-pointer-to-`CSquare`, so you need to do this:

```
(*tempIt)->getName();
```

Comment: Cheers man, I figured it out literally 2 minutes ago xD I guess just writing it out away from the rest of my code helps me think about it.

Comment: That happens sometimes. It's called the "Rubber Duck Effect" (see http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RubberDucking).

Comment: I was aware of the concept, but very interesting read, served as a nice distraction from my work, now to plow on.

Answer (score 4):

You need an extra dereference:

```
(*tempIt)->getName();
```

The reason is that what you are storing inside the vector are pointers, so `*tempIt` is a reference to a pointer that you need to dereference again to access the `CSquare` object.